# IE AJAX Responses Trim All Data After Null (0x00) Characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, mime-types

In Internet Explorer (IE6, IE7, and IE8) null characters ("0x00") and any characters after are trimmed off of ajax responses (data).

I have a loop of AJAX requests like the following:

```
var pages = 10;
var nextnoteid = 0;

for (isub = 1; isub <= pages; isub++)
    {
    var c = "http://www.site.com/application.exe?id=" + nextnoteid;
    $.ajax(
        {
        url: c,
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        success: function(data)
            {
            var start = data.indexOf("NEXTNOTEID") + 10;

            // save the id of the next note to retrieve
            nextnoteid = data.substring(start, start + 16).trim();
            data = data.substring(0, start - 10);

            // append note to DOM
            $("#printarea").append("<pre class='pxprintpage'>" + data + "</pre>");
            }
        });
    }
```

The responses are returned in the following format (_ represents a 0x00 character):

> ```
> Note Title
> Note Author
> ... simple text note ...
> __________NEXTNOTEID__________9827482998274829__________
> ```

How can I get this data after 0x00 in IE6, IE7, and IE8 without changing the respone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE browsers like to terminate strings at NULL characters. The solution is to replace the null characters with spaces. Unfortunately, this appears to be the only solution, which does not exactly fit the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will really help, but try setting the `dataType` field in the options passed to .ajax() to `"text"`.

If that doesn't fix the issue, take a look at the `dataFilter` option passed to [.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). It allows you to specify a callback function to handle the raw response.

Comment: I have tried all the documented dataTypes. The dataFilter function also terminates the string at the first 0x00.